# CORS header access control missing django on digital ocean NGINX and gunicorn

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, nginx, django-cors-headers

Response in Console:-

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blissedmaths.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/media/topics/4276769703/4276769703.svg. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I have user django-cors-headers, a Django App that adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to responses.

My setting.py file is

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
    'students',
    'commons',

]

         CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
    CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
    CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
        'DELETE',
        'GET',
        'OPTIONS',
        'PATCH',
        'POST',
        'PUT',
    )
    CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        'accept',
        'accept-encoding',
        'authorization',
        'content-type',
        'dnt',
        'origin',
        'user-agent',
        'x-csrftoken',
        'x-requested-with',
    )

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

The image that is giving me error coming from Digital ocean space is

```
   <script>
                function fetchXML(url, callback) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
                console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders)
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function (evt) {
                //Do not explicitly handle errors, those should be
                //visible via console output in the browser.
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    callback(xhr.responseXML);
                }
                };
                xhr.send(null);
                };


                    fetchXML("{{a.image.url}}",function(newSVGDoc){
                    //import it into the current DOM
                    var n = document.importNode(newSVGDoc.documentElement,true);
                    document.querySelector('.{{a.topic|slugify}}-image').appendChild(n);
                        }); 



            </script>
```

This page is live at https://blissedmaths.com/myclassroom/polynomial/

I have added everything needed in setting.py by still header is not coming. I tries Jquery and AJAX also. But no use.

How to fix this. **Is it requires some javascript also or only this backend is enough?**

*I tried to add header via Nginx conf also. But didn't worked.*
How can I solve this, by python code or by Jquery/JS or by server configuration files. No method worked for me actually. But image is coming from source.
*Please provide a fix for this.*

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but is there any chance you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have two 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware' in settings file. CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's CommonMiddleware

Comment: Thanks Jibin, I tried this but still it is not working.

Comment: remove                 xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*'); and try it

Comment: I did, no benifit.

Comment: Have you solved that?